# Eclipse constantly crashing - could not resolve mylyn module

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

My installation of Eclipse 2022-09 is crashing constantly, either it freezes and then crashes, or just crashes silently.
I've noticed that it happens when the code completion tooltip is triggered, but not always.
On restart the error log contains the following

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui [2581]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui; bundle-version="[3.8.0,4.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui; bundle-version="3.25.2.v20200814-0512"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui [2580]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed; bundle-version="1.0.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed; bundle-version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [2553]
                No resolution report for the bundle.  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses constraint violation.
  org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'javax.xml.bind' from resources javax.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.2.0.v201105210648"; osgi.identity="javax.xml.bind"] and jakarta.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20201118-1818"; osgi.identity="jakarta.xml.bind"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=javax.xml.bind)(bundle-version>=2.2.0))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: javax.xml.bind
  javax.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.2.0.v201105210648"; osgi.identity="javax.xml.bind"]

Chain 2:
  org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.17.2.v20200813-0821"; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=com.sun.xml.bind)(bundle-version>=2.2.0))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; bundle-version:Version="2.3.3.v20201118-1818"; osgi.wiring.bundle="com.sun.xml.bind"
  com.sun.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20201118-1818"; osgi.identity="com.sun.xml.bind"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.xml.bind)(&(version>=2.3.3)(!(version>=2.3.4))))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.xml.bind
  jakarta.xml.bind [osgi.identity; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="2.3.3.v20201118-1818"; osgi.identity="jakarta.xml.bind"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1852)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Short of a reinstall, can this be fixed?

After removing Mylyn, as recommended, the crashes are still occuring, with the following in the error log view
Still crashing, pasting in code into a window is causing the crashes, albeit intermittently.
This is in the error log

```
eclipse.buildId=4.25.0.I20220831-1800
java.version=19
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_IE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.core.resources
Warning
Fri Oct 14 15:48:23 IST 2022
The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
```

Comment: The root cause is that plugin/bundle `org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed` _"is exposed to package 'javax.xml.bind' from resources javax.xml.bind [...] and jakarta.xml.bind"_. So, if you do not use Mylyn, uninstalling Mylyn should fix it (Mylyn is not included in the 2022-09 release anymore). Alternatively, uninstalling anything that uses `jakarta.xml.bind` should also work. (For me Mylyn works in Eclipse 2022-09, having the plugin/bundle `javax.xml.bind`, but not `jakarta.xml.bind`.)

Comment: Thanks, I've removed mylyn, hopefully that will solve things

Comment: Mylyn removed, but crashes still happening intermittently, original question updated

Comment: Unfortunately this is not much information and I have not seen this myself or heard about it from others. Better run Eclipse with Java 17 as part of Eclipse: _JustJ Adoptium OpenJDK Hotspot JRE Complete_ instead of the Java 19 installed on your system (which can cause problems by plugins you have installed). You might also try a fresh workspace (via `-data ...`).